# How to remove specific DIV tag from HTML value of a sitecore field using powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to remove the below tag from an HTML object containing the sitecore field value in the form of HTML.

I want to remove this and set back the remaining HTML in the same field.

```
<div class = "abc"> Some other tags and HTMLs </div>
```

I referred the below link but no luck.

[Using Powershell Extensions to remove empty <p> tags from all rich text fields](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20795/using-powershell-extensions-to-remove-empty-p-tags-from-all-rich-text-fields)

Please also someone tell me that what will be the Regex pattern for
`<div class = "abc">` for sitecore powershell.

Comment: Is the html markup from the rich text field?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes

Comment: You want to remove the first div only or the div including the other tags within that div?

Comment: div including the other tags within that div

Comment: Really need something like HtmlAgilityPack to parse the whole partial doc. This is because you need to relocate the child content of the div. Using a regex to find and replace will be risky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet to remove the HTML tags.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"
$richTextField = $item["Text"]
$richTextHtml = $richTextField -replace '<.+?>' 
Write-Host $richTextField
Write-Host "New Value"
Write-Host $richTextHtml
```

I tested it on the home item.
Below is the result in the console.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I believe this will remove every div tag within the HTML, in my case I need to remove only those divs, which are having some particular class, For e.g. <div class ="a" I want to remove but I don't want <div class="b" to be removed within the HTML.

Comment: I will see if this is possible as we would need to find the closing div tag also to make sure the HTML is valid.

Comment: Can anyone suggest on the solution here. 

 [string]$content = $GetContent
 $content =  $content.Replace('<div class="parsys"><div class="heading section"><h1 class="news heading01">@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("NewsTitle")</h1></div>', "")

This is not working for me.